Creating aligned tabs similar to ms word and libreoffice
One feature present in Microsoft Word is the tab settings (right click->paragraph->tabs).  This allows tab stops to be created, where you press the tab key and it will move the cursor to the next tab stop.  You can also change how the text aligns at that tab point (left-aligned, centered, right-aligned).
How can I get the same effect in LaTeX?  I have tried using the tabto package, but this appears to only work with left-aligned text.  I have tried using the flushright environment, but this only works if the tab location is the right margin.  I have also used \hfill, but this works basically the same as flushright did.
Are there any packages that can replicate how it works in word processors?  Any custom LaTeX code?


I have no idea what the Word layout is that you mention but perhaps the tabbing environment (standard latex, no package needed)?

It depends on what you want to do. Maybe tabular could also be a solution, or \makebox Please describe your aim in more detail.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

@JasperHabicht I want a solution just like tabto, but with the option to either left, right, or center-align the text on the specified tab stop.  For example, if I was writing lecture notes, I might use this for a section headers where I have the course title, lesson title, class code, and date.  Each has its own position and anything left of the center needs to be left-aligned and anything right of center right-aligned.  For simplicity of typing, I would want the ability to just type \tab and have latex know where the next tab stop is and how the text should be aligned at that tab stop.

Well, the most obvious solution is mimic tabulations with a simple table  without vertical and horizontal lines (I mean any tabular-like  environment, not the table float), but here you have two less obvious options, that are more near to the concept of tabulations in word processors and old typewriters:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\begin{document}
\section*{Using the tabbing environment}
The \texttt{tabbing} environment allows you to set tab stops and align text in columns.
\begin{tabbing}
  First Column \= Second Column vey width \= Third Column \kill % Set tab stops
  Name \> Age \> City \\
  Alice \> 25 \> New York \\
  Bob \> 30 \> Los Angeles \\
  Charlie \> 22 \> Chicago \\
\end{tabbing}
\section*{Using the tabto package}
The \texttt{tabto} package allows you to set specific tab stops manually by specifying the positions in the document.
\subsection*{Set the Tab positions:}\TabPositions{0cm,2cm,7cm,}
\hspace{\parindent}Name \tab Age \tab City \par
  Alice \tab 25 \tab New York \par
  Bob \tab 30 \tab Los Angeles \par
  Charlie \tab 22 \tab Chicago \par
\subsection*{Or just the number \ldots}\NumTabs{3}
  Name \tab Age \tab City\\ 
  Alice \tab 25 \tab New York\\ 
  Bob \tab 30 \tab Los Angeles\\ 
  Charlie \tab 22 \tab Chicago 
\subsection*{Or manually in each case \ldots}
\tabto{2cm}Name\tabto{5cm}Age\tabto{8cm}City \\
\tabto{2cm}Alice\tabto{5cm}25\tabto{8cm}New York \\
\tabto{2cm}Bob\tabto{5cm}30\tabto{8cm}Los Angeles \\
\tabto{2cm}Charlie\tabto{5cm}22\tabto{8cm}Chicago \\
\end{document}


In all of these examples, the text is left aligned.  I haven't found a way for either of these packages to support right alignment.  The tabular environment approach would work, but wouldn't be as elegant a solution as I would like to find.

@thenickman100 In this old answer I made a macro \tab{<text>} using a \makebox that set the left alignment with the optional argument [l]. You can clone the macro definition to make two new the macros, said  \tabc{} and \tabr, and  just change [l] to [c]  and [r] in the respective definitions.
